# Git squash commit and the review of future pull requests

Tags: git, azure-devops

When we do a PR with squash commit between environment branches (ex: dev and master) the next PR will ignore that the previous commit was already merged and show 2 commits to merge making the review more difficult:

[image]

So, one may use squash merge for feature branch > dev but not for environment branches like dev > master:

[image]

Are these assumptions correct? Or is there a way to make the PR ignore previous PR'd commits? (I'm using Azure DevOps)

Comment: Not get your latest information, just want to check whether below answer is helpful for you? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which can also benefit for others who has same puzzle with you. Also, feel free to leave comment below if still has any puzzle about it:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing to understand about "squash merge" is that it is *not a merge*. It's effectively a cherry-pick plus squash-rebase.

So when you have this:

```
    A-B-C (feature)
   /
--X (dev)
```

and you ask to squash feature onto dev, you get this (the commits of `feature` are *copied* onto the end of `dev`):

```
    A-B-C (feature)
   /
--X-AA-BB-CC (dev)
```

followed by this (the copies are squashed down to a single commit):

```
    A-B-C (feature)
   /
--X-D (dev)
```

It is true that D was created by squashing copies of A, B, and C, but there is nothing in the history that reflects that fact; indeed, there is nothing that reflects any idea that D has *anything at all* to do with `feature`. And nothing at all happened to `feature` — so it is still sitting there. If that isn't what you want, delete `feature` after the merge.

Personally, I think squash merges are a very bad idea, because they erase history. And that is the problem you are having, precisely: there is no history that anything was ever done with `feature` (because nothing *was* done with it).